# Java 1.7 or later is required to run Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

When I type

`$ drillbit.sh start`

it shows me this error:

```
ERROR: Java 1.7 or later is required to run Apache Drill.
```

although I have the latest version of java

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

also my $JAVA_HOME is set correctly in .profile

What could cause such issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, after investgating a little bit I have found that the config file drill-config.sh
checks the java version with bad regex:

> ```
> "$JAVA" -version 2>&1 | grep "version" | egrep -e "1.4|1.5|1.6" > /dev/null
> if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
>    fatal_error "Java 1.7 or later is required to run Apache Drill."
> fi
> ```

The regex "1.4" matches 144 which is the update number in java version I have.
So the floating point should be escaped to be "1\.4"

And this finally solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a Jira to fix this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-5698 and open PR.